# tikz: drawing arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make the left vertical lign arrow-style as the right one?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,3) -- (0,0)
  node[below] {$0$} -- (3,0) node[midway,below] {$x_A$}
 node[below] {$1$} -- (3,3);
 \draw[red,thick] (0,1) -- (3,2);
 \path (1,0.5) node {liquido} (2,2.5) node {vapore};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You draw the whole axis system in one path. `->` only adds an arrow tip at one end of the path. Therefore you need `<->` to have two arrows tip at two ends.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->] (0,3) -- (0,0)
  node[below] {$0$} -- (3,0) node[midway,below] {$x_A$}
 node[below] {$1$} -- (3,3);
 \draw[red,thick] (0,1) -- (3,2);
 \path (1,0.5) node {liquido} (2,2.5) node {vapore};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]